# Symfony2 & Annotations & Choices Validation: How to store and retrieve choices options?

Tags: symfony, validation, callback, annotations

I have a dynamic list of choices to display in a form and I just want to maintain them in one place, as these are not the only datasets I have to care for.

To validate those choices in the Entity over choices-CallbackValidator I would need to specify a fix class and function where the choices would be returned.

This seems not right as I am still learning Symfony2 and the DIC concept and then I would not expect to specify a concrete callback function/class, but a service or think of another way to solve this.

I would like to give not a classname, but a service name as callback. Am I wrong here?

I need the list of options to

- fill the form
- to validate the entity with annotations
- to know where to send emails (later)

Setup now:

services.yml - The DataManager defined with service_container and the Form as a service (I don't know if this is right):

```
services:
  data_manager:
    class:  TestBundle\Service\DataManager
    arguments:
            - "@service_container"
            - %tc_data.list%
  support_type_form:
    class: TestBundle\Form\Type\TicketType
    arguments: ["@service_container"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

The Form:

```
class TicketType extends FormType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $theChoices = $this->getContainer()->get('data_manager')->getTheChoices();
        ...
    }
}
```

The Entity:

```
class Ticket
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Choice(callback = {"NotAServiceReference", "getTheChoices"})
     */
    private $the_list_field;
}
```

So I have the list of data in the service, but how would you suggest I retrieve the choices to validate the Entity?

Another solution I thought of was using the Callback validation (link 2), but even there in the docs it sais:

```
// somehow you have an array of "fake names"
$fakeNames = array();
```

How did/would you solve this?

References:

1. See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#supplying-the-choices-with-a-callback-function (click annotations)
2. See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#the-callback-method

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid passing service_container to your services.  The basic idea behind dependency injection is to inject only those objects that are actually needed.
2. So for your DataManager you probably only want to inject the entity manager.
3. For your TicketType, inject your DataManager service.  At which point you can do $this->dataManager->getChoices() in a nice generic fashion.

As far as validating within the entity itself, not really sure you need to.  The form->isValid() will already check to make sure your choices are valid.  But I can understand the expectation that Assert\Choices should be able to specify a service.

From here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

> It is not currently possible, however, to specify a service as a constraint. To validate using a service, you should create a custom validation constraint and add that new constraint to your class.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped. to 1. I avoided passing the service_container as you suggested. The point would be that testing is easier if I don't have to setup the whole container each time for each test. to 2. The DataManager now gets injected only the list of data coming from parameters.yml. to 3. did it exactly as you said, looks clean now. And I had in mind, that I could write my own Validation and Constrain when I sent this and you confirmed my thought. Thanks!